# how can i set text of my layout beside each other in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Here  i want my date beside my title that is beside razin and in corner of listviev not below the title.  I had used android deafult layout of listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/myyellow">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Edit: I got this as per your suggestion but I want date in the corner.

[image]

Comment: Can provide the layout which you are adding in the listview I think this can be solved by using relative layout

Comment: Sreedev >>u mean JAVA code??

Comment: How are you adding the components in listview???Using default Arrayadapter or using your own adapter?

Comment: Using database cursor adapter

Comment: Customize baseadapter and using your own component for creating the listview will solve your problem ...

Comment: sreedev >> But i want to do in this only.can u help me here in this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `ListView` item top-level layout a `LinearLayout` with "horizontal" orientation. Then the `TextViews` will be side-by-side.

You can alternatively use a `RelativeLayout` and then easily place each `TextView` in any location.

The default `ListView` layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` looks something like this:

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

Start with this.
To use a "horizontal" `LinearLayout` you must change the `TwoLineListItem` into `LinearLayout` with "`android:orientation="horizontal`" and add an additional `TextView`.
To use a `RelativeLayout` you must change the `TwoLineListItem` into `RelativeLayout`, add the additional `TextView`, and place them however you want.

Comment: I had tried oreintation =horizontal but nothing happened...can u tell me where can i edit in xml?

Comment: Edit the XML in a new Layout file in your `res/layout` directory.

Comment: but for the listview i have only one xml that is shown above

Comment: You need a second XML file for the list items. It will be accessed by your Adapter and is used to layout each row.

Comment: No i dont have aany other xml because i have used default android layout.You can see my code.

Comment: Replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` with your new item layout, perhaps `R.layout.my_list_item`. Then your file is `res/layout/my_list_item.xml` and your adapter is specified as: "`new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.my_list_item, notesCursor, from, to);`".

Comment: no i just want to set the date in the right corner thats it.can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Ok. There are several ways. I see your screenshot now. I see that you used a `LinearLayout`. Therefore, the easiest method for you is to make the width of your `LinearLayout` and of your 2nd `TextView` "fill_parent". This will put the right side of your 2nd `TextView` all the way to the right side of the screen. Then, make the "gravity" of your 2nd `TextView` "right" (this is equivalent to right-justification).

Comment: no i have used relativeLayout:

Comment: hey dude its ok i got it what i want :)  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the component. Adding this to the list using the Baseadapter will give you what you needed. You can add using the getview function in the baseadapter.This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) will help you

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="Sub content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: hey you can see the screenshot in DAVID answer thats what i got but i want size of text large as "textAppearanceLarge" is not enough size size for me and date should be set in corner

Comment: i edited my ans you can make a customized adapter using this layout